# Unable to execute a Less CSS loop properly

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I'm trying to create different loops (the class should have a different background colours), but I'm able to only compile the first one.

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyWgdo?editors=1100

And the code that i'm using:

```
@temp0-9: #1976d2;
@temp10-20: #00bcd4;
@gap1: 10;
@gap2: 10;


.first (@i) when (@i > 0) {
  span.temp-@{i} {
    display:block;
    background: @temp0-9;
  }
  .first(@i - 1);
}
.first(@gap1);

.second (@i) when (@i > 15) {
  span.temp-@{i} {
    display:block;
    background: @temp10-20;
  }
  .second(@i - 1);
}
.second(@gap2);
```

The compiled result is the following:

```
 span.temp-9 {
  display: block;
  background: #1976d2;
}
span.temp-8 {
  display: block;
  background: #1976d2;
}
span.temp-7 {
  display: block;
  background: #1976d2;
}
span.temp-6{
  display: block;
  background: #1976d2;
}
span.temp-5{
  display: block;
  background: #1976d2;
}
span.temp-4{
  display: block;
  background: #1976d2;
}
span.temp-3{
  display: block;
  background: #1976d2;
}
span.temp-2{
  display: block;
  background: #1976d2;
}
span.temp-1{
  display: block;
  background: #1976d2;
}
span.temp-0{
  display: block;
  background: #1976d2;
}
```

Only 10 entries instead of 20 that I was expecting.

Any help?

Comment: `@i` is not greater than 15.

Comment: if i change @i to 0, the dark blue is not displayed and the compiled result is not temp-{from 0 to 20} but only temp-{0-9} repeated twice: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyWgdo?editors=1100

Comment: Well that doesn't change the fact that the input is less than 15, does it? Anyway, what is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: same as the one before, but having span.temp-0 to span.temp-9 with this background: #1976d2 (dark blue) and span.temp-10 to span.temp-20 with this other color: #00bcd4(light blue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your loop's guard conditions wrong. The guard condition states that loop will be executed only when input (`@i`) is greater than 15 but the value that is passed as input (`@gap2`) is only 10 and hence the loop never gets executed.

For the output that you are expecting, change the guard condition like in the below snippet. Now, the guard is `@i > 0` and so the loop will get executed but the selector interpolation in the 2nd mixin uses the `@j` variable (which is `@i + @gap1`). Since we are adding `@gap1` to the loop's index, the no. value appended to the selector will be greater than 10 for the second loop.

```css
@temp0-9: #1976d2;
@temp10-20: #00bcd4;
@gap1: 10;
@gap2: 10;

.first (@i) when (@i > 0) {
  span.temp-@{i} {
    display:block;
    background: @temp0-9;
  }
  .first(@i - 1);
}
.first(@gap1);

.second (@i) when (@i > 0) {
  @j: @i + @gap1;
  span.temp-@{j} {
    display:block;
    background: @temp10-20;
  }
  .second(@i - 1);
}
.second(@gap2);
```

[**Demo @ Less2CSS.org**](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40temp0-9%3A%20%231976d2%3B%5Cn%40temp10-20%3A%20%2300bcd4%3B%5Cn%40gap1%3A%2010%3B%5Cn%40gap2%3A%2010%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn.first%20(%40i)%20when%20(%40i%20%3E%200)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20span.temp-%40%7Bi%7D%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20display%3Ablock%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20background%3A%20%40temp0-9%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20.first(%40i%20-%201)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn.first(%40gap1)%3B%5Cn%5Cn.second%20(%40i)%20when%20(%40i%20%3E%200)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%40j%3A%20%40i%20%2B%20%40gap1%3B%5Cn%20%20span.temp-%40%7Bj%7D%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20display%3Ablock%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20background%3A%20%40temp10-20%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20.second(%40i%20-%201)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn.second(%40gap2)%3B%22%7D)

---

If you have multiple such gaps, then writing a single loop (with complex logic) would be better than writing multiple loop mixins. Below is a sample:

```css
@gaps: 46, 19, 3, 4, 4, 14; /* the gap array */
@temps: red, crimson, orange, gold, yellow, green; /* the temps corresponding to each gap */

.gaps-loop(@i, @prevgap) when (@i > 0){
  @gap: extract(@gaps, @i); /* extract each gap one by one based on loop index */
  @temp: extract(@temps, @i); /* extract the temp corresponding to each gap */
  .span-gen-loop(@j) when (@j < @gap){
    /* loop to generate spans - executed as many times as @gap */
    @k: @j + @prevgap; /* add current index to previous gaps - this generates a running number from 0-90 */
    span.temp-@{k}{
      display:block;
      background: @temp;
    }
    .span-gen-loop(@j + 1);
  }
  .span-gen-loop(0);
  .gaps-loop(@i - 1, @prevgap + @gap); /* send current gap + previous gap(s) */
}
.gaps-loop(length(@gaps), 0); /* loop as many times as there are gaps */
```

Comment: Lets say that I need to have 6 gaps, and they are like this:
gap1: 14 | gap2: 4 | gap3: 4 | gap4: 3 | gap5: 19 | gap6: 46 how would you do that? basically they are range of temperatures and the colors needs to change according to the temperature (0-100)

Comment: It would be nice if the down voter cared enough about SO's quality to comment. Use your down vote for constructive criticisms, improving the quality and not trolling.

Comment: Im going to try your solution soon and I'll let you.know. I upvoted your answer as at a glance it seams to work (I don't care if it messy as long as it works). I'll get back to you soon. Thanks for now

Comment: Perfect. It is working as i wanted. Thanks again for your support and patience :)